# Displaying column sum at bottom of column using Union in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem where I want to show the sum of the three last columns at the bottom of the column using the `UNION` this is the query:

```
select a.app_file_id, a.app_fname,a.app_lname, l.tertiary_interest,l.loan_life,l.commit_date,
max(case  when date(r.receipt_date)<='2012-4-01' and r.receipt_date = (select max(r.receipt_date) from receipt_history r where date(r.receipt_date)<='2012-4-01' ) then amount_owed else 0 end),
sum(case when r.receipt_on='Principal' and r.receipt_date >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(2012, '-04-01'),'%Y-%m-%d') and r.receipt_date <=  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(2012, '-03-31'), '%Y-%m-%d') + interval 1 year then r.receipt_amount end), 
max(case  when r.receipt_date<=STR_TO_DATE(concat(2013,'-4-01'),'%Y-%m-%d') and r.receipt_date = (select max(r.receipt_date) from receipt_history r where r.receipt_date<=STR_TO_DATE(concat(2013,'-4-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')) then amount_owed else 0 end) 
from applicant a 
left join loan l on l.l_app_file_id=a.app_file_id 
left join receipt_history r on r.r_app_file_id=a.app_file_id 
group by l.loan_id
union
select '', '','','','','',sum(max_pay_april_G),sum(fiscal_Prin_G),sum(final_bal )
from(
a.app_file_id, a.app_fname,a.app_lname, l.tertiary_interest,l.loan_life,l.commit_date,
max(case  when date(r.receipt_date)<='2012-4-01' and r.receipt_date = (select max(r.receipt_date) from receipt_history r where date(r.receipt_date)<='2012-4-01' ) then amount_owed else 0 end) as max_pay_april_G,
sum(case when r.receipt_on='Principal' and r.receipt_date >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(2012, '-04-01'),'%Y-%m-%d') and r.receipt_date <=  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(2012, '-03-31'), '%Y-%m-%d') + interval 1 year then r.receipt_amount end) as fiscal_Prin_G, 
max(case  when r.receipt_date<=STR_TO_DATE(concat(2013,'-4-01'),'%Y-%m-%d') and r.receipt_date = (select max(r.receipt_date) from receipt_history r where r.receipt_date<=STR_TO_DATE(concat(2013,'-4-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')) then amount_owed else 0 end) as final_bal
from applicant a 
left join loan l on l.l_app_file_id=a.app_file_id 
left join receipt_history r on r.r_app_file_id=a.app_file_id 
group by l.loan_id
)q;
```

I know it may seem confusing due to the fact that I am using 3 tables and the column names may pose a problem but I would really appreciate some help if anyone could aid me in analysing the query and see where I went wrong, so far the error message I am getting is directing me to Line 13, I do hope I made the question clear enough to get some assistance. Thanks you very much

Comment: Few things. It is poor practice to use aggregate functions without a `GROUP BY` statement. Are you sure you want to be using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`?

Comment: I will stick with using the union for now, I just cannot spot where the problem is though

Comment: Start by breaking down your query. Run the query before and after `UNION`...

Comment: Tried that and still getting the same error

Comment: You're being too vague. What error? If it's a line #, what is on that line #?

Comment: In the question I stated which line I am having the error and the error message is just saying error 1064 you have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: Could you kindly point out the specific code that is on that line as I do not trust simply counting to that line number in the snippet. Also, are you receiving the same error when you run the upper and lower queries individually?

Comment: The lines are the same with both the snippet and the actual query, and the error messages goes on to say the error is near :`max(case  when date(r.receipt_date)<='2012-4-01' and r.receipt_date = (select max(r.receipt_date) from receipt_history r where date(r.receipt_date)<='2012-4-01' ) then amount_owed else 0 end) as max_pay_april_G,` line13

Comment: What is the result of `select max(r.receipt_date) from receipt_history r where date(r.receipt_date)<='2012-4-01'`?

Comment: Have you considered using WITH ROLLUP http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html ?

Comment: yes i did but it doesnt really do the job as i want it to and i figured the problem